# How to change value of specific field of MySql database using Javafx application?

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

I'm working on a project that requires access to user data base. I created a javafx panel that displays all users from database and their data in a table. I wanted to make a method that change value of selected user's status from user to admin and vice versa, but no matter what I did I couldn't get it to work properly. Here is a code of the method:

```
private void grantAdminRights() {
        admninrightsButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent admnrights) {
                try {
                    Connection con = DbUtil.getInstance().getConnection();
                    User selectedUser = userTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                    Integer selectedUserID = selectedUser.getUserID();
                    String grantAdminRights = "UPDATE `androidshop`.`userdatabase` SET `status`='admin' WHERE `userID`="+selectedUserID +"";
                    String grantUserRights = "UPDATE `androidshop`.`userdatabase` SET `status`='user' WHERE `userID`="+selectedUserID +"";
                    String statusValidation = selectedUser.getStatus();

                    if (statusValidation.equals("user"))
                    {
                        selectedUser.setStatus("admin");
                        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(grantAdminRights);
                        ps.setInt(1, selectedUser.getUserID());
                        ps.executeUpdate();
                    } 
                    else if (statusValidation.equals("admin")) 
                    {
                        selectedUser.setStatus("user");
                        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(grantUserRights);
                        ps.setInt(1, selectedUser.getUserID());
                        ps.executeUpdate();
                    } 
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Invalid field value");
                    }
                } 
                catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                }

        });
    }
```

Contents of User class:

```
public class User {
    public int userID;
    public String username;
    public String password;
    public String status;
    public String firstname;
    public String lastname;
    public String shippingadress;
    public String preferredpayment;
    public String purchaseditems;

    public enum PreferredPayment {
        CreditCard, PayPal, OnReceipt;
    }

    public int getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(int userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getShippingadress() {
        return shippingadress;
    }

    public void setShippingadress(String shippingadress) {
        this.shippingadress = shippingadress;
    }

    public String getPreferredpayment() {
        return preferredpayment;
    }

    public void setPreferredpayment(String preferredpayment) {
        this.preferredpayment = preferredpayment;
    }

    public String getPurchaseditems() {
        return purchaseditems;
    }

    public void setPurchaseditems(String purchaseditems) {
        this.purchaseditems = purchaseditems;
    }
public User(int userID, String status, String username, String firstname, String lastname, String shippingadress, String preferredpayment, String purchaseditems) {
        this.userID = userID;
        this.username = username;
        this.status = status;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.shippingadress = shippingadress;
        this.preferredpayment = preferredpayment;
        this.purchaseditems = purchaseditems;
    }
}
```

Method that fills the table with data (working properly):

```
public void buildData() {
     data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
     try {
         Connection con = DbUtil.getInstance().getConnection();
         String sql = "SELECT * FROM userdatabase";
         ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
         while(rs.next()) {
             data.add(new User(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2),  rs.getString(3), rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6),  rs.getString(7), rs.getString(8), rs.getString(9)));
         }
     } catch (SQLException ex){
         ex.printStackTrace();   
     }

        idColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, Integer>("userID"));
        statusColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("status"));
        usernameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("username"));
        firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("firstname"));
        lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("lastname"));
        adressColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("shippingadress"));
        paymentColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("preferredpayment"));
        itemsColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User, String>("purchaseditems"));

        userTable.setItems(null);
        userTable.setItems(data);
    }
```

Displayed table content:

[table content] https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn4hT.jpg

How could I get grantAdminRights method to work as intended? I be grateful for any feedback and tips about code.

Thanks to everybody that finds time to answer.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions or errors?

Comment: With this code, Im getting only "Invalid field value" communicate from my method. Before I tried changing (statusValidation.equals("user")) to (statusValidation == user) and I got a NullPointerException, also before some changes to querries I had an IndexOutOfBounds.

Comment: So what is the value of `statusValidation`?

Comment: Its supposed to be only either "user" or "admin", and only those values are displayed in a table. If its not producing desired results, it must be neither of them. There is probably something wrong with how I tried to get the value, but I couldnt think of anything else. Now when I tried out this method Im getting: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0). Im a bit confused at this point.

Comment: The second error is pretty clear: you are calling `setInt(...)` on your prepared statement, but it has no parameters in it. For the first one, what is the actual value you have for `statusValidation` when you are getting the `"Invalid field value"` message?

Comment: Ok, I understand the second error now, thank you. As for first one, It is supposed to be only one of those two values, in userdatabase, I even made status column's value an enum with only possible values "user" and "admin". I thought I made an error in typing, but I checked several times and it was ok. I updated my question with link to picture with table contents.

Comment: You still haven't answered the question. I know it's *supposed* to only be `"admin"` or `"user"`, but *what value are you actually getting in that case*?

Comment: Why do you insert the user id using string concatenation if you later use `PreparedStatement` to do the same. Should be `...\`userID\`=?"` if you want to use `PreparedStatement.setInt`. Furthermore you made 2 rather poor naming choices: Any person encountering a method named `grantAdminRights` would assume this method does the assignment of the rights; instead it registers a handler to do this. You also used `admnrights` as the name of the `ActionEvent` parameter; it does not contain any information about rights though...

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I refactor the code after I make it work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I made following changes to the method, and now it works as intended:

```
private void grantAdminRights() {
            admninrightsButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent admnrights) {
                    try {
                        Connection con = DbUtil.getInstance().getConnection();
                        User selectedUser = userTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(); 
                        String grantAdminRights = "UPDATE `androidshop`.`userdatabase` SET `status`='admin' WHERE `userID`= ?";
                        String grantUserRights = "UPDATE `androidshop`.`userdatabase` SET `status`='user' WHERE `userID`= ?";
                        String statusValidation = selectedUser.getStatus();

                        if (selectedUser != null && statusValidation.equals("user"))
                        {
                            selectedUser.setStatus("admin");
                            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(grantAdminRights);
                            ps.setInt(1, selectedUser.getUserID());
                            ps.executeUpdate();
                        } 
                        else if (selectedUser != null && statusValidation.equals("admin")) 
                        {
                            selectedUser.setStatus("user");
                            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(grantUserRights);
                            ps.setInt(1, selectedUser.getUserID());
                            ps.executeUpdate();
                        } 
                        else {
                            System.out.println("Invalid field value");
                            System.out.println(statusValidation);
                        }
                    } 
                    catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    }

            });
        }
```

Thanks to everybody for the tips that allowed me to get there.